# Is there a way to use DateTime without it taking into account leap years?

Tags: c#, datetime

I need to calculate the time span between two dates but without taking into account leap years - as if every year was exactly 365 days.

Before I go re-writing `DateTime` is there something in .NET that will allow me to do this? I cannot find anything built in.

Comment: i would be interested in knowing how creating a fake date range might be useful. I mean if it's to compare to another calendar base the CultureInfo and datetime already account everything so i'm curious.

Comment: No, this is for a real world problem. Believe it or not it's for a pensions calculator I have to write at work which should specifically NOT take into account leap years. Baffling, yes, but I am just doing what my spec says.

Comment: How would you calculate the non leap-sensible timespan for leap-sensible `DateTime`? I don't think you thought this over well.

Answer (score 1):

Use this method to get all the days between two dates, irrespective of any year to be a leap year

```
long DaySpan(DateTime t1, DateTime t2)
{
  days = (t2 - t1).TotalDays;
  for(int i = t1.Year; i< t2.Year; i++)
  {
     if(Date.IsLeapYear(i))
     {
       days--;
     }
  }
  if((Convert.ToInt32(t2.Month) != 1 || Convert.ToInt32(t2.Month) != 2)&&Date.IsLeapYear(t2.Year))
  {
     days--;
  }

  if((Convert.ToInt32(t1.Month) != 1 || Convert.ToInt32(t1.Month) != 2)&&Date.IsLeapYear(t1.Year))
  {
     days--;
  }
  return days;
}
```

Comment: @Jon the complete idea behind this snippet is to get the total days between two date and then remove the no of extra days which were because of leap year.
Also one has to consider that the year in which the two date lies are leap year or not and also if one has remove days, only if the earlier date is before 29th March (if leap year) and older date is after 29th March (if leap year)

Comment: Thanks Niley, I'm perfectly capable of writing code. I was more interested in finding out if there is anything already there that allows me to do this.

Answer (score -3):

No, DateTime represents date and time as it is presented on your PC, leap years and all.

Comment: I'm curious to know why this was downvoted. The question asked was "Before I go re-writing DateTime is there something in .NET that will allow me to do this? I cannot find anything built in.", there is nothing built into .NET to do what Jon was asking for, you have to write code to handle this like Nilay has in his answer. I did not provide a solution to the problem, because it was not asked for.